# Using import from a Vue Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a components.js file that looks like  this:

```
import { lookCoordinate } from './tools.js'; // I get: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Vue.component('coordform', {
  template: `<form id="popup-box" @submit.prevent="process" v-if="visible"><input type="text" autofocus refs="coordinput" v-model="coords"></input></form>`,
  data() {
    {
      return { coords: '', visible: false }
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.toggle)
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.toggle)
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(e) {
      if (e.key == 'g') {
        if (this.visible) {
          this.visible = false;
        } else
          this.visible = true;
      }
    },
    process() {
      lookCoordinate(this.coords) // Tried to import from tools.js
    }
  }
});
```

But I'm getting:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

How do I import a function from another plain JS file and use it within a Vue component?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, corrected it. JS is not semicolon aware so did not affect the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us tools.js?  And not sure what you mean by JS is not semicolon aware.  Missing a semicolon can drastically change how the code is executed due to automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: Also, this is an issue with import/export, not with Vue.  Are you using webpack or rollup (or something else along those lines) to bundle these into a script, or is this being parsed by the browser and throwing the error?

Comment: @wjervis i'm not using any webpack technology. Works fine in standard JS but now i'm trying to glue in some Vue.

Comment: What browser do you use? - You cant just `import {}` something from a file if you do not bundle your code. If your app is served from a web-server for example it would not know how to fetch "./tools.js".

Comment: @PatrickHollweck Chrome. I did not have any issue. I'm using a local server (live server plugin for VSCODE) it just works. In fact, import is a vanilla JS feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Does the script tag have `type="module"` specified?

Comment: Yes I totally get that, Importing is a vanilla feature. But if you would, for example, use a browser that does not support es6 modules yet, then it would give you that error. - And most browser do not support it yet, Thats why bundlers like webpack exist. Can you show us how you load the script ? - Aka the html script tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported if you add script with `type="module"`:

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error if trying to load a Javascript file without ES6 support enabled.  The parser does not understand the syntax of `import` is as it begins parsing the file.

Check your webpack or vue-cli settings to make sure that you are transpiling the code.

For instance, a browser does not know what `import` means, and neither does plain old node unless enabling experimental support.

You can also change it to:

```
const  lookCoordinate  = require('./tools.js').lookCoordinate;
```

and see if that gives you an error.  That format does almost exactly the same thing.

If using `import` from a browser, also enable module support, as suggested by Orkhan Alikhanov in the comments.

```
It is supported if you add script with type="module". e.g: 
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Import is widely supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility

I do not want to mess up with Vue Cli or anything like that. I'd embedded the function into the Vue component to avoid this?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla You cant "just use" the `require` function - It is not inbuilt. You either use a bundler to pre-process that for you or you use the module type in your script tag in a supported browser

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla It is supported if you add script with `type="module"`. e.g:  `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov yes! I forgot to add type="module" to the component.js import line in the main file! Put is as an answer please.

Comment: The first paragraph in the link that OP posts: >The import statement cannot be used in embedded scripts unless such script has a type="module".

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this without `{}`.

```
import { lookCoordinate } from './tools.js'
```

`{}` is used when you define multiple functions inside tools.js

like,

```
import { lookCoordinate, lookCoordinate2 } from './tools.js'
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: `{}` is used for single imports too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module

Comment: Importing without `{}` is for importing default exports, which only works if the module declares a default export.